# webpack create bundle and replace string

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

My current webpack-3 confing creates bundle.js from many angular-1 modules.

load.js loads bundle.js?1234 via require.js and i need change URL query parameter every rebuild (prevent caching).

I tried string-replace-loader, but it doesn't work with straightforward config. Because of load.js is not in entry files list.

So how to process file but not include it in bundle?

```
module.exports = {
context: "/app",
entry: ['source1.js', 'source2.js', 'source3.js'],
output: {
    path: "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
plugins: [ new BabiliPlugin() ],
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /load\.js$/,
    loader: 'string-replace-loader',
    query: {
      search: 'bundle.js', // simple test, check it actually run
      replace: '-replaced-'
    }
  }
]}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do:

```
filename: "[name].[hash].bundle.js"
```